# How to count a rows in column with bool values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `users` which consists of three columns `id`, `username` and `password`.

I am trying to get a count of the rows which have less than 8 numbers of characters in `password`.
My code:

```
# Calculating the length of user's passwords
users['length'] = users.password.str.len()

# Flagging the users with too short passwords`

users['too_short'] = pd.cut(users['length'], bins=[0,7,300], labels=[True,False])

print (users[users['too_short'].any(1)])

# Counting and printing the number of users with too short passwords
print(users['too_short'].count())

# Taking a look at the 12 first rows
users.head(12)
```

It gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Categorical cannot perform the operation any
```

Column `too_short` has a value either `True` or `False`. I am trying to find a way to count the number of rows in this column based on the boolean values, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
users['too_short'] = users['length'] < 7

print(users[users['too_short']])
print(users['too_short'].count())
```